# AWK with $0 replace pattern with new string using sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file with multiple job contents like :

```
insert_job: 18132_TAL_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON   job_type: CMD 
command: $ADM_BIN/pear_generic_wrapper.ksh 
owner: gpadmin
permission:
```

Here, I needed to add one more line for each insert_job as:

```
insert_job: 18132_TAL_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON   job_type: CMD 
condition: 18132_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON
```

So, basically 2 steps (first to replicate line job name; then replace `18132_TAL_` with `18132_` in 2nd copied line printed as condition: )

To do this, I go till this point for each insert_job line:

```
insert_job: 18132_TAL_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON   job_type: CMD 
insert_job: 18132_TAL_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON
```

Now, to update the 2nd line to replace insert_job with condition, and `18132_TAL_` with `18132_`, I am stuck.

I am trying to have code something like:

```
$ cat input.dat | awk '($0!~"job_type") {print $0|sed "s/insert_job/condition/"} 1'
```

But, sed doesn't work here and it gives syntax error.

Can you please help with correct syntax of using sed after `print $0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/insert_job/{
  val=$2
  sub(/_[^_]*/,"",val)
  $0=$0 ORS "condition: " val
  val=""
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk code from here.
/insert_job/{                    ##Checking condition if string insert_job is found in a line then do following.
  val=$2                         ##Creating variable val whose value is $2(2nd field) of current line.
  sub(/_[^_]*/,"",val)           ##Substituting _ till next occurrence of _ with NULL in val here.
  $0=$0 ORS "condition: " val    ##Concatenating ORS(new line) then string condition and variable val here.
  val=""                         ##Nullifying variable val here.
}
1                                ##1 will print edited/non-edited line here.
'  Input_file                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***Output will be as follows:***

```
insert_job: 18132_TAL_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON   job_type: CMD 
condition: 18132_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON
command: /pear_generic_wrapper.ksh 
owner: gpadmin
permission:
```

Comment: Works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '
    { print }
    sub(/^insert_job/,"condition") {
        sub(/_TAL/,"")
        print $1, $2
    }
' file
insert_job: 18132_TAL_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON   job_type: CMD
condition: 18132_D_DS_PEAR_AUTORECON
command: $ADM_BIN/pear_generic_wrapper.ksh
owner: gpadmin
permission:
```

You never need sed when you're using awk and awk is not a shell, it's a completely separate tool with it's own language, syntax, and semantics so you shouldn't be trying to call other UNIX tools from it using shell syntax.